# Mongodb sparse index and general index

Tags: mongodb, indexing, sparse-matrix

I have created a collection with 100 documents (fields `x` & `y`), and created a normal index on field`x` and a sparse index on field `y`, as shown below :

```
for(i=1;i<100;i++)db.coll.insert({x:i,y:i})

db.coll.createIndex({x:1})
db.coll.createIndex({y:1},{sparse:true})
```

Then, I added a few docs without fields x & y as shown below:

`for(i=1;i<100;i++)db.coll.insert({z:"stringggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggggg"})`

Looking at `db.coll.stats()`, I found the sizes of the indexes:

```
storageSize:36864
_id:32768
x_1:32768
y_1:16384
```

As per the definition of sparse index, only documents containing the indexed field `y` are considered, hence `y_1` occupies less space. But `_id` & `x_1` indexes seem to contain all the documents in them.

If I perform a query - `db.coll.find({z:99}).explain('executionStats')`

It is doing a COLLSCAN and fetching the record. If this is the case, I am not clear on why MongoDB stores all the documents under `_id` & `x_1` indexes, as it is a waste of storage space. Please help me understand. Pardon my ignorance if i missed something.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 4):

In a "normal" index, missing fields are indexed with a `null` value. For example, if you have index of `{a:1}` and you insert `{b:10}` into the collection, the document will be indexed as `a: null`.

You can see this behaviour using a unique index:

```
> db.test.createIndex({a:1}, {unique:true})
{
    "createdCollectionAutomatically" : true,
    "numIndexesBefore" : 1,
    "numIndexesAfter" : 2,
    "ok" : 1
}

> db.test.insert({b:1})
WriteResult({ "nInserted" : 1 })

> db.test.insert({c:1})
WriteResult({
    "nInserted" : 0,
    "writeError" : {
        "code" : 11000,
        "errmsg" : "E11000 duplicate key error collection: test.test index: a_1 dup key: { : null }"
    }
})
```

Both `{b:1}` and `{c:1}` are indexed as `a: null`, hence the duplicate key error message.

In your collection, you have 200 documents:

- 100 documents with `{x:..., y:...}`
- 100 documents with `{z:...}`

And your indexes are:

- `{x:1}` (normal index)
- `{y:1}` (sparse index)

The documents will be indexed as follows:

- 200 documents will be in the `_id` index, which is always created by MongoDB
- 200 documents will be in the `{x:1}` index, from `{x:.., y:..}` and `{z:..}` documents
- 100 documents will be in the `{y:1}` index

Note that the index sizes you posted shows the same ratio as the numbers above.

Regarding your questions:

- The `_id` index is for MongoDB internal use, see [Default _id index](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/indexes/#default-id-index). You cannot drop this index, and attempts to remove it could render your database inaccessible.
- The `x_1` index is there because you told MongoDB to build it. It contains all the documents in your collection because it's a normal index. In the case of your collection, half of the values in the index are `null`.
- The sparse `y_1` index is half the size of the `x_1` index because only 100 out of 200 documents contain the `y` field.
- The query `db.coll.find({z:99})` does not use any index because you don't have an index on the `z` field, hence it's doing a collection scan.

For more information about indexing, please see [Create Indexes to Support Your Queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/create-indexes-to-support-queries/)